# What options do I have for reading eBooks on an Android tablet?

Tags: ebook-readers, android

I have recently purchased an Asus Nexus 7 (2013) and would like to use it for reading. To that end, I have had a look through many of the various applications touting themselves as "eBook readers" on the Google Play store and come across the usuals like the Kindle application but also some others like Aldiko, Kobo and Moon+

What options do I have for reading eBooks on an Android tablet?

How do these stack up against each others in terms of features?

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit too broad. There are many dozens of book reader apps, with varying features. To be answerable, you need to clarify which features are a must-have for you, or what criteria to use for filtering down from dozens to at most half-dozen.

Comment: Would this question be better asked like [this](http://pastebin.com/Vp3jDPiY)?

Comment: Definitely MUCH MUCH better. And I would strongly recommend to split those 3 bullet points from pastebin into 3 different questions as well

Comment: @Flyk: That question would be better, but there are several questions that could be asked separately (some of which may have already been answered on the site).

Comment: It's better to create 3 new questions, and let this one get closed (or delete it if it starts getting too many downvotes). People tend to frown when a question gets so dramatically edited that existing answers don't make sense anymore :)

Comment: I see you created the 3 questions. You may want to edit this one to point to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DVK has commented, your question is a little broad, without specific requirements. However, if all you are looking for is an objective, feature comparison of Android ereader software, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software) is your friend.

There is a breakdown of the following (as of Dec-23-2013):

1. [File formats supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software#File_formats_supported)
2. [Navigation features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software#Navigation_features)
3. [Display features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software#Display_features)
4. [Edit-tool features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software#Edit-tool_features)
5. [Book source management features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software#Book_source_management_features)
6. [Other software e-book readers for Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software#Other_software_e-book_readers_for_Android)
7. [See also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software#See_also)
8. [References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software#References)
9. [External links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software#External_links)

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to answer properly as asked, since there are too many options.

As such, the best approach is to:

- Take a [well regarded reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software) that supports all the features you need and most formats you need (personally, I love FBReader and Cool Reader, but your mileage will vary with what features you need).
- Then augment them with extra apps tailored to formats that you require but that the first 1 or 2 apps can't read (e.g. you may need a separate app for DJVU books, and probably a standalone PDF reader).